# Easily scale android application for smaller screen sizes

Tags: android

Right now I have an application I built that is built for android 10.1 inch screens (tablet) and I would like to to be able to be scaled so that it work on the kindle fire (7 inch screen). What would the easiest way to do this be?

Edit:
So I've taken the advise that the majority of the people in this tread have given and replaced all of the absolute layouts with relative layouts and I am using margins left,right,top,bottom, to place them, but still the button images are too large and they are misplaced, how can i do this so it works correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some design criterias for developing android applications to make them work in different configurations like screen size:

1. use different layouts for different configurations
2. use fill_parent and wrap content properties in layouts
3. do not give hard coded pixel values
4. do not use absolute layout
5. provide different drawables for different configurations

for more look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Sorry i guess i worded that badly, i developed the app

Comment: @Peter You would take the same approach and provide an update.

Answer (score 1):

Following the best practices guidelines is always good but sometimes you simple need a whole new layout for different screen sizes.  Android allows you to create different layouts files for different screen sizes.  To do this you can create a new folder under 'res' called 'layout-large' or 'layout-large-land' for landscape.  The same is also true for 'layout-xlarge' and 'layout-xlarge-land'.  You can just add another xml layout file in these directories with the same names and same ids and android will automatically pick the right one based on the users screen.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it depends on your application.  If you built it so that it would work with tablets and you didn't specify non-percentages for your widths and heights, it will probably automatically scale to the proper size on the Kindle Fire.

Honestly, get a test device (or emulate the size using the Android Emulator) and see what happens.  Very likely, if you followed proper design patterns, the app will Just Work (TM) on the Kindle Fire.

If it doesn't, you might want to take a look at how you're specifying the sizes of your elements.  Using Pixels or any other type of pixel-based numeric measurement will do some strange things to your UI.  Instead of widths and heights, use paddings and margins defined with density independent pixels.  This will help your app scale properly.

I recently wrote an app testing it only on mobile phones, and was pleasantly surprised when I purchased a tablet, and the app scaled up perfectly - with no warning from Android about different ways to scale it.

Answer (score 0):

Realy easy, but not recommend because it can pixialize images, is Enabling Screen Compatibility Mode.

Try adding this:

```
<supports-screens android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="320" />
```

OR this:

```
<supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="320" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml.

To understand whats happening check here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html#Enable